# Could you tell me why these threads don't overlap on the first case and do on the second?

Tags: java, multithreading

If I run the main method on "MyClass" and use the synchronized block with the lock object from that one (lock), each thread prints out the count sequentially even though the lock is acquired within the for block.

Conversely, if I use the lock declared within the Worker class (lock2), the threads do overlap in the print statement executions.

*(I've added a concatenation to the System.out.format() to add more places where the thread can be interrupted by the OS).*

```
class MyClass {
    private static Object lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        (new Thread(new Worker(),"Thread 1")).start();
        (new Thread(new Worker(),"Thread 2")).start();
        (new Thread(new Worker(),"Thread 3")).start();
        (new Thread(new Worker(),"Thread 4")).start();
        (new Thread(new Worker(),"Thread 5")).start();
    }

    private static class Worker implements Runnable{
        private int runCount = 1;

        private Object lock2 = new Object();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                synchronized (lock){
                    System.out.format("s" + "%s: runCount = %d\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), runCount++);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could you tell me why this difference occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lock2`, you are synchronizing on a different instance of `lock2` per `Worker`. Each `Thread` will have its own object to synchronize on, so there will be no blocking of the other threads.

If you synchronize on `lock`, each thread will share the same object because it is a static instance, so threads will be blocked.

Comment: Thank you!. 
Still though, If I acquire the lock inside the for loop, wouldn't that lock be potentially released once the synchronized block is compleated, thus alowing the forloop of another runnable instance to acquire the lock at that time and allowing for some interleaving?

Comment: Yes, potentially. It may or may not occur. You could see it all happen sequentially as you're seeing where the other threads aren't unblocked in time to execute, or you could see the other threads take over. There's no guarantee what behavior will happen. If you put a `Thread.sleep(1000)` after you release the lock, you may see some interleaving.